# Posterior probability of the max of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, likelihood

Let $y$ be a uniformly distributed random variable over the interval $(0, \theta)$, whereby Pr$(\theta = 1)$ = Pr$(\theta = 2) = \frac{1}{2}$ are the prior probabilities of the parameter $\theta$. If a single data point $y = 1$ is observed, what is the posterior probability that $\theta =1?$

Can anyone give me the idea on how to tackle this question? I have no idea.

Comment: At what point are you stuck?

Comment: Not clear with the question

Comment: Do you know the definitions of uniformly distributed random variable, prior probability, posterior probability? Any of these? Have you managed to compute the posterior probability of something (in some other question, for example)?

Comment: Yes I do know that (Prior probability)*(evidence) $\implies$ (Posterior probability) and uniform distribution is a distribution that has constant probability.

Comment: According to the usual definition of intervals, $(0,1)$ does *not* include the value $1$, whence if $y=1$ is observed, it is impossible that $\theta=1$ regardless of any prior probability assigned to it.